# data.table assignment by reference using lapply and also returning the rest of the columns

Tags: r, data.table

I want to be able to apply a function over a subset of columns, and return those columns that have been manipulated along with the rest of the data columns that weren't touched. Is there a way to do this with data.table. I wasn't able to figure out the syntax.

In this example I have NAs and want to overwrite them with something else for a few different columns. I need a way to also return other columns that weren't touched.

```
library(data.table)

# make data set
a <- sample(c(letters[1:5], NA), 50, replace=TRUE)
b <- sample(c(LETTERS[1:5], NA), 50, replace=TRUE)
c <- sample(runif(50))

x <- data.table(a,b,c)

# function to apply to a single column
overwriteNA <- function(vec, new="") ifelse(is.na(vec), new, vec)

# Only returns .SDcols but would like to also include rest of columns in data.table
x[, lapply(.SD, overwriteNA), .SDcols=c("a", "b")]

# Need something along these lines
x[, `:=` lapply(.SD, overwriteNA), .SDcols=c("a", "b")]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
x[,  c("a", "b") := lapply(.SD, overwriteNA), .SDcols = c("a", "b")]
```

Edit:

Per OPs additional request.

```
myCols <- c("a", "b")  
x[, (myCols) := lapply(.SD, overwriteNA), .SDcols = myCols]
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to do so with a character vector of column names? This doesn't seem to work. 

`myCols = c("a", "b")`; 

`x[,  myCols := lapply(.SD, overwriteNA), .SDcols=myCols]`

Comment: Why do you use eval() ?

Comment: @skan Because you need to tell `data.table` to evaluate `myCols`. Otherwise it will create a new column called `myCols`. Though you can evaluate it with just parenthesis

Comment: Hello, @DavidArenburg , and what's the difference between using (myCols) and .(myCols) ? , I've seen the latter option, with a dot, in some examples.

Comment: @skan `.()` is short for `list()`

Comment: Then here does the same?

Comment: @skan, no, `list` isn't evaluating the expression within it. So you can't use it in this case